# Jquery fadeIn() multiple divs one after another when scrolled to the bottom each time

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok for my website, I want to be able to load more `divs` using a `fadeIn()` when the user scrolls to the bottom

the first example of the code i had in mind was this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

$(window).on('scroll resize', function (e) {
  /*desktop > 768px*/
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone1 == false && $(window).width() > 768) {
    $(".breakpoint").fadeIn(2500).css({
      "display": "grid"
    });
    $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime, #home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").hide();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone2 == false) {
      $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({
        "display": "grid"
      });
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1 && oncedone3 == false) {
        $("#home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({
          "display": "grid"
        });
        oncedone1 = true;
        oncedone2 = true;
        oncedone3 = true;
        //oncedone4 = true;
      }

    }
  }
  /*mobile / < 768px*/
  //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone1v1 == false /*&& $(window).width() < 768*/) {
  //$(".breakpoint").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
  //$("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime, #home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime, #home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").hide();
  //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone2v1 == false) {
  //  $("#home-page-best-anime, .home-page-best-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
  //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone3v1 == false) {
  //  $("#home-page-season-anime, .home-page-season-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
  //if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && oncedone4v1 == false) {
  //  $("#home-page-genre-anime, #home-page-action-anime, .home-page-action-anime").fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
  //oncedone1v1 = true;
  //oncedone2v1 = true;
  //oncedone3v1 = true;
  //oncedone4v1 = true;
  //}
  //}
  // }
  //}
});
```

but then this would have some bugs and fadeIn the whole page not just the `div` so then I thought why not use the .each function to fadeIn when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page for each of the `divs`

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
            $('.bpshow').each(function (i) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() && $(window).width() > 768) {
                    $(this).fadeIn(2500).css({ "display": "grid" });
                }
            });
        });
```

Here's the website I'm working on: [AniBUY All Anime](https://54x1.github.io/AniBuy/pages/indexv2.html)

Comment: first about your design. It's not a responsive page. Don't you want use % instead of px?

Comment: you can use Ajax load masonry for infinite scroll with loadmore and add different effects to it using animate.css - https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/masonry/  OR  use waypoint.js with animate.css.

Comment: firstly im trying to get the page to look good on pc then do responsive and i dont wanna use plugins as i want to learn how to do it from scratch

Comment: how do u use % in resize in jquery i was trying to find out myself as well as im basing this off bootstraps and css grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it this worked for me

```
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function (i) {
        $('.bpshow').each(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() && $(window).width() > 768) {
                $(this).fadeIn(1500).css({ "display": "grid" });
            }
        });
    });
```

but i needed to add bpshow to the breakpoint-1 for each class as well as the -2 for each class as seen on the website